# Convert double value from little endian to Big endian

Tags: c++, linux

I am converting from little endian to big endian and back to little checking
    is it right or wrong please help me

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>


double dx = 122992001003000;

//A method little to big endian

double bEndian(double d) {

    int *p0 = (int *) &d;
    int *p1 = p0 + 1;

    printf("1: %x %x\n", *p0, *p1);

    int tmp = *p1;
    *p1 = htonl(*p0);
    *p0 = htonl(tmp);

    printf("2: %x %x\n", *p0, *p1);

    return *(double *)p0;
}

//A method  big to little endian

double lEndian(double d) {
    int *p0 = (int *) &d;
    int *p1 = p0 + 1;

    printf("3: %x %x\n", *p0, *p1);

    int tmp = *p1;
    *p1 = ntohl(*p0);
    *p0 = ntohl(tmp);

    printf("4: %x %x\n", *p0, *p1);

    return *(double *)p0;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{       
    double d1 = bEndian(dx);

    double d2 = lEndian(d1);

    printf("5: %.0f\n", d2);

    if ((*(double*) &d2) == dx)
      printf("6: %.0lf\n", *(double*) &d2);
    else
      printf("7:%d\n", d2);

    return 0;
}
```

some time it give me result 122992001003129 why?
 also using ntohl or htonl have no difference ?? is it only for convention 
i.e. network to host and host to network

Comment: And if you print the value of `dx` directly it is correct?

Comment: `ntoh` and `hton` just switch the order of the bytes (on most machines, on big endian ones they do nothing), so yes they are the same under different names for clarity.

Comment: strict aliasing rules broken.

Comment: @Iluvatar:  Of course, there are other byte orderings than just "big-endian" and "little-endian".  If the host ordering was 0321 (ie rotated by one byte), then ntoh and hton would be different.  (I know of no architecture with such a byte ordering - even historically.)

Comment: I suspect your problem today is that 122992001003000.0 cannot be represented exactly in double format.

Comment: Tomorrow, you will discover that you byte reverse a perfectly ordinary double value ... and it turns into a signalling NAN.  You *really* need to return the network byte ordering as `struct netDouble { unsigned char bytes[sizeof(double)]; };`

Comment: @MartinBonner what is the problem with turning into signalling NAN? No floating point operations are done on the returned value.

Comment: Ah.  I was under the impression that just the `return` statement would load the sNAN into an FP register, and cause a signal.  That may not be correct.  (I would strongly advise the OP to test it though.)

Comment: @some programmer yes it give same value

Comment: @Jarod42 do you comments about strict aliasing rule

Comment: `some time it give me result ...` Define *some time*. Do you mean that different executions on the same computer have randomly different output?

Comment: hexadecimal value of dx is as on little endian machine is A1EB7E00 42DBF713 and after reversing it gives 13F7DB42 7EEBA1 I run it on redhat 6.0 ,6.5 and 7.2 all give same result

Answer (score 5):

Here is a function that will change the endianness.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>

template <class T>
T change_endian(T in)
{
    char* const p = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&in);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(T) / 2; ++i)
        std::swap(p[i], p[sizeof(T) - i - 1]);
    return in;
}

int main()
{
    double d = 122992001003000;
    printf("%f\n", d);
    d = change_endian(d);
    printf("%f\n", d);
    d = change_endian(d);
    printf("%f\n", d);
}
```

Output:

```
122992001003000.000000
0.000000
122992001003000.000000
```

Comment: I don't think there's any strict aliasing issues with the original solution. It's allowed to examine any object as char array.

Comment: @khuttun yes, that part seems like “hiccup” from my end. I’ll edit the answer

Answer (score 3):

Easy:

```
#include <endian.h>
#include <stdint.h>

double  src_num = YOUR_VALUE;
int64_t tmp_num = htobe64(le64toh(*(int64_t*)&src_num));
double  dst_num = *(double*)&tmp_num;
```

However, there're certain quirks: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Floating_point

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef union
{
    double d;
    unsigned char s[8];
} Union_t;

// reverse little to big endian or vice versa as per requirement
double reverse_endian(double in)
{
    int i, j;
    unsigned char t;
    Union_t val;

    val.d = in;
    // swap MSB with LSB etc.
    for(i=0, j=7; i < j; i++, j--)
    {
        t = val.s[i];
        val.s[i] = val.s[j];
        val.s[j] = t;
    }
    return val.d;
}
```

Comment: I have added comments in the code to make it more understandable. What the loop does is swap 0th byte with 7th byte, 1st with 6th, .... I have used union of double with array of 8 chars since double is 8 bytes.

Answer (score -2):

Simple reversal of four bytes should work

```
double ReverseDouble( const double indouble )
{
   double retVal;
   char *doubleToConvert = ( char* ) & indouble;
   char *returndouble = ( char* ) & retVal;

   // swap the bytes into a temporary buffer
   returndouble[0] = doubleToConvert[3];
   returndouble[1] = doubleToConvert[2];
   returndouble[2] = doubleToConvert[1];
   returndouble[3] = doubleToConvert[0];

   return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Two problems:  Firstly double is eight bytes, not four.  Secondly, even if you fixed that, returning as double is problematic; perfectly ordinary double values can be transformed into signalling NAN values.